# Why validation is not working properly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am having an input field and a submit button:

```
        <form action="" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="sponsar_name" id="sponsar_name" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn-submit" name="submit" onClick="validate()" >
    </form>
```

```
      function validate()
    {
        var flag = 0;
    if(document.getElementById("sponsar_name").value == null || document.getElementById("sponsar_name").value == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("sponsar_name").style.borderColor = 'red';
            flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                        document.getElementById("sponsar_name").style.borderColor = '';
                }

                if(flag==1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }

    }
                     </script>
```

I have applied a function `onClick` on submit button .this I have applied for validation.

When I click on submit button it shows red background of textbox but refreshes the page immediately.

If the textbox is blank it should not refresh the page, but in my code it is doing so.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `onClick="return validate()"` does the trick.

Comment: top comment is right. and you have good code. the first sugestion creating varibale for document.getElementById("sponsar_name").

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="sponsar_name" id="sponsar_name" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn-submit" name="submit" onClick="return validate()" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either `onClick="return validate()"` or `onSubmit="return validate()"`. It will fix the problem.

using `onClick="return validate()"`

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="sponsar_name" id="sponsar_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn-submit" name="submit" onClick="return validate()" >
</form>
```

using `onSubmit="return validate()"`

```
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="text" name="sponsar_name" id="sponsar_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn-submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way,

`<input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn-submit" name="submit" onClick="return validate()" >`

And when you will return false in your method, your form won't be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Change you form like this: remove `onClik` function and add the `onSubmit` on form header

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
           <input type="text" name="sponsar_name" id="sponsar_name" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn-submit" name="submit"/> 
    </form>
```